# Is disassembly of standard gcc programs trivial, or just as difficult as video game ROMs?

Tags: disassembly, disassemblers, gcc, rom

I am attempting to do some reverse-engineering of ARM binaries, with the ultimate goal of reverse-engineering GBA ROMs. Of course, GBA ROMs contain a mixture of code and data, so a standard disassembler that just converts the hexdump to equivalent ARMv4 assembly won't work because of the parts that correspond to data. So clearly disassembling GBA ROMs is a tough task. (Please correct me if I'm wrong on any of that - I'm very much still learning.)

My question is, do standard C programs compiled to ARMv4 with `gcc` on Ubuntu have the problem I explained above of producing a mixture of data and code in the binary? If so, what kinds of programs have this (all of them, or only some special cases?)

Comment: I guess the tooling for ELF files (an assumption, as you don't say!) and ARMv4 is generally better and more versatile. Basically what I mean is that more generic tools will work than for GBA. So in that sense it's perhaps a little easier. But tools are just one variable in the equation ...